# Python Selenium Get PageSource of XHTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsp, selenium, pdf

I was wondering if there was a way to print the entire html path. I am trying to verify some text in a pdf xhtml file pop-up and can not get to to. My hope is to get the entire page source and verify the text is in there. However .page_source seems to only give me the url and description and I am looking to get each line of code.

Comment: did you test the proposed solution ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to make selenium find the starting page tag (html) and  get all the source related code.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html").get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

[Documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=getAttribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Output example:

```
<html webdriver="true"><head>

<title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge, and advance their careers">

    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
    <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Stack Overflow">
    <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/">

......
```